# Zooming using \framezoom

Tags: beamer, zooming

I am creating a presenation in `beamer`. I am using `\framezoom{}` to zoom in a few critical area in a picture. The problem is that when I zoom in, I get out of bounds.

**Zoomed Frame**
[image]

My code is

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \begin{columns}[T]
  \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
   \vspace*{1cm}
   \begin{itemize}\small
    \item Event-by-event aquisition
    \item NIM
    \item Computer Automated Measurement and Control-CAMAC
    \item Java
   \end{itemize}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
   \framezoom<1><2>[border=0](2.3cm,0cm)(3cm,2.5cm)
   \framezoom<1><3>[border=0](5.2cm,0cm)(5cm,2cm)
   \framezoom<1><4>[border=0](2.3cm,2cm)(8cm,5cm)
   \centering
   \vspace*{0cm}
   \hspace*{-2cm}\visible<1->{\includegraphics[scale=0.19]{ControlPanel}}
  \end{column}
 \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I place the zoomed area in center and not getting out of bounds?